# Error While Test The Project On Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven

i am using maven i don't have more knowledge about maven  when i am install my project then it will successfully build but when i am test my project with maven it will give me an error like

```
Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory
```

i gave  all permission to my project directory detail error as below so how can i resolve my 
problem and how to run my project

so please help me

E
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 24 seconds

[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 27 17:44:59 IST 2011

[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/84M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please try to format the output next time.

Answer (score 1):

> [INFO] Unable to copy an artifact to
>   the working directory Embedded error:
>   /home/nayan/workspace/ONiT/mediaPlayer/target/classes
>   (Is a directory) [INFO]

This looks like some of the previous tests are still running at this point and blocking maven from writing in the target directory. 
As this seems to be an reactor build, do the modules themself build correctly ? I.e. can you run mvn test in each module directory seperately ?

Comment: ok thanks for your reply now when i am individual test project that time my project all projects are success fully test                                                                                           Actually we  dir structory given by client is   ONiT
[INFO]   ONiT Commons
[INFO]   ONiT Media Player
[INFO]   ONiT App Client
[INFO]   ONiT Servlets                                                                              when i am test whole project It will give an error like i have gave                            but when i have test each one by one it will test success fully